# How safe is it to store user access level and email in Json Web Tokens

Tags: javascript, node.js, json-web-token

Would it be safe to store the user access level/admin level and email which determines what data they can retrieve? or should I store the token in the database verify the token on each request and look up data that way?

Comment: Usually, the best scheme is for the token to represent a validated userID and then for things like privileges to be looked up as needed based on the userID that the token represents.  That also allows privileges to be modified by some authorized agent without making the token be out-of-date.  Imagine you want to revoke some privilege.  If it's in the token, you have to somehow revoke the token itself.  If the privilege is looked up at needed, then a change takes place immediately without having to revoke any token.

Answer (score 0):

If you sign your JWT, you make token's content read-only. If that's not safe enough, you can encrypt its content.